# SharePoint Search Results page Refiners and Quick Navigation

Tags: search, sharepoint, navigation

On the search results page in the search center the refiners override the placement of the local quick navigation.

I would like to show them both: the quick navigation on top.

I create a new layoutpage with webparts etc.. that derives from "the" custom master which show now the refiners on the right which works but nicest would be to show them underneath the quick menu.

Is there a way without modifying the masterpage? I think that involve in the refiners section placing on top of it some control that would display the quick navigation.

im thinking of using jquery to just take that part of the dom and insert it into the correct location after rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Only two options are changing the master page (preferred option) or using javascript (I really would advise against this option).